# I was trying to install netfilterqueue for Scrapy (Python) and this error came can anyone help me with this

Tags: python

```
root@kali:~/PycharmProjects/net_cut# pip install netfilterqueue
Collecting netfilterqueue
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/c4/8f73f70442aa4094b3c37876c96cddad2c3e74c058f6cd9cb017d37ffac0/NetfilterQueue-0.8.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for netfilterqueue ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-OpqHKj/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpgaDKrapip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'netfilterqueue' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-Ra3Yar/python2.7-2.7.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c netfilterqueue.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/netfilterqueue.o
  netfilterqueue.c:437:10: fatal error: libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h: No such file or directory
   #include "libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py clean for netfilterqueue
Failed to build netfilterqueue
Installing collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py install for netfilterqueue ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-OpqHKj/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wjXNHQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'netfilterqueue' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-Ra3Yar/python2.7-2.7.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c netfilterqueue.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/netfilterqueue.o
    netfilterqueue.c:437:10: fatal error: libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h: No such file or directory
     #include "libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-OpqHKj/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wjXNHQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-OpqHKj/netfilterqueue/
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing `libnfnetlink-dev`, it still did not work for me. I had to install `libnetfilter-queue-dev` like so: `apt install libnetfilter-queue-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Install the corresponding Kali Linux package for what in Debian's called [libnfnetlink-dev](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libnfnetlink-dev), then retry.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: If you now have a `libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h`, if netfilterqueue can’t build it’s legit to blame Kali and/or Pip, isn’t it?

Comment: Maybe blaming them at their own forums work.